# Does the implementation of \ escape character work similarly in JavaScript and PHP or is there any difference in both the implementations?

Tags: javascript, php, string, html-escape-characters

I've a following working JavaScript code which makes use of **\ escape character**

This backslash escape character turns special characters into string characters

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>

      var x = 'It\'s alright';
      var y = "We are the so-called \"Vikings\" from the north.";

      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x + "<br>" + y; 

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

The output of above code in browser is as below :

```
It's alright
We are the so-called "Vikings" from the north.
```

My question is does the implementation of \ escape character work in similar manner in PHP as well or are there any differences in implementation in PHP?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is does the implementation of \ escape character work in similar manner in PHP as well [as JavaScript]

Yes.

> or are there any differences in implementation in PHP?

Yes. There are two significant differences with regard to the backslash as an escape:

- In PHP, the use of the backslash as an escape is very different depending on whether you use a single-quoted string (`'foo'`) or double-quoted string (`"foo"`).
- The escape sequences are different, although there is a lot of overlap.

#### Single-quoted vs. Double-quoted

In PHP there's a big difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in terms of escape sequences (and more, see ¹ below). [Details in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), but in single-quoted strings, the backslash is only an escape character if the next character is a `'` or a backslash; in all other cases, it's a literal backslash. So

```
echo 'foo\nbar';
```

outputs

```
foo\nbar
```

whereas

```
echo "foo\nbar";
```

outputs

```
foo
bar
```

In JavaScript, the only difference between a single-quoted string and a double-quoted string is whether a `'` or `"` can appear unescaped. The escape sequences that you can use in both are exactly the same.

#### Escape sequences

The [PHP documentation linked above](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-literals-string-literals) lists the PHP escape sequences. The [JavaScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-literals-string-literals) lists the JavaScript escape sequences, although [MDN's list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) is easier to read. Again, there's a lot of overlap (both are inspired by C), but there are also differences.

---

¹ And as long as we're talking about PHP strings and JavaScript strings, note that in double-quoted PHP strings, variables are expanded; in single-quoted ones, they aren't. JavaScript doesn't have that, but it does have something similar (and even more powerful) with the new [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in ES2015.